# Application.Current.MainPage vs Navigation.PushAsync() vs Navigation.PushModalAsync()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I'm developing an Xamarin Forms App (PCL) that does NOT need a back button. That app has three pages : a `SplashScreenPage` to load data, a `LoginPage` if the user needs to login and a `RootPage` which is a `MasterDetailPage`. I was wondering what was the best option to navigate between pages (to avoid memory leaks for example):

**First solution:**

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new ContentPage();
```

**Second solution:**

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new ContentPage()));
```

then

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
ClearNavigationStack();
```

**Third solution**

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new ContentPage()));
```

then

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
ClearModalStack();
```

Comment: Best option in terms of what? None of these options should have memory leaks if implemented correctly (barring Xamarin.Forms internal leak issues). Have you tried implementing any of these solutions yet and seeing what happens?

Comment: First, thanks for your quick response @WillDecker. 
I implemented the first solution I proposed and it seemed good. But I was wondering (with that solution) if the previous current page was deleted after calling Application.Current.MainPage = new ContentPage();
I tried today to implement the second solution but the NavigationBar appeared even if I called NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); (maybe I do something wrong ?) 
So I tried the third solution, the NavigationBar don't appear anymore, but I want to clear the modal stack and I don't know what is the best way to do that.

Comment: With respect to the first solution, the previous page should get cleaned up after you assign your new page to MainPage. I actually think that would be your best bet in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know what is the solution to clean up the previous page ? With the second solution I can use the RemovePage method of the Navigation object but I don't see how to do with the first one.

Comment: I was advised to use the Garbage Collector method Collect to dispose of elements which are not in use anymore (then clear the previous page). What do you think about that solution @WillDecker ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As describe by @will-decter none of the above solutions could cause memory leaks if implemented correctly.

You can use any of the above solutions. And generally you need not to do anything to clear previous page. Garbage Collector automatically do that for you (Not immediately but after some time based on some condition). Consider first solution:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new Page1();
```

Now if you assign new page like this.

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new Page2();
```

As Page1 is no longer in use, GC will collect Page1 object after some time when GC try to reclaim some memory. You can also use GC.Collect() to force GC to reclaim memory immediately but as GC.Collect() operation is expensive so I would suggest you should not call it from your code rather optimize your code so don't need to call it.

But if your page is subscribe to an event and does not unsubscribe it then in that case GC cannot collect that the page even if you call GC.Collect() method. So make sure that you unsubscribe any subscribed event like this:

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
     protected override void OnAppearing()
     {
         base.OnAppearing();
         MyEntry.TextChanged += MyEntry_TextChanged;
     }

     protected override void OnDisappearing()
     {
         base.OnDisappearing();
         MyEntry.TextChanged -= MyEntry_TextChanged;
     }
}
```

(You can skip unsubscibe if event was subscribe from xaml as in that case Xamarin Form uses WeakReference)

This will ensure MainPage is collected by GC when needed.

I would suggest to read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/) article to get better insight how GC works in Xamarin and how can you increase your application performance.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/

Comment: Ok thank you ! I remove the Collect method's calls from my App and I unsubscribe my events the different pages subscribed. Just one last thing, what do you think about that answer: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/303771#Comment_303771
Is it correct or not ?

Comment: No that is not the correct answer. I have edited the code for better understanding. In sort GC.Collect() just try to clean up object little bit earlier which will happen automatically after some time. And also GC.Collect() does not guarantee that it will clean up your previous page.

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot <3

Answer (score 4):

think best option to navigate between pages is

in App.cs

```
public App()
{
    var nav = new NavigationPage(new Login());
    MainPage = nav;
}
```

then on Login success click:

```
void OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterPage());
}
```

Not need to add "NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);"

Comment: I know I don't need to add NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); with that solution... I was wondering how clear the previous page with that...

Comment: Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterPage()); is reset Navigation stack