# How to check if the ContentPage exists yet after a Task.Delay

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a page with a delay of 5 seconds because a loading is run to the user, is needed because the webservice is too fast and the user need to view the loading. The Page02 has a cancel button, when this is clicked then the app go to Page01.

The problem is when I cancel the operation, then the code after the delay run anyway.

How can I to avoid this?

```
public Page02()
{
    InitializeComponent ();           
    GetData();
}

private async void GetData()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    MainPage.actualPage.PushAsync(new Page03());
}

private void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage = new Page01();
}
```

Comment: So, what you want to do? When you click in cancel, what are you expecting? To stop the GetData method and then navigate to Page01?

Comment: When I click cancel button, I expect to delete all the information about the flow of the previous steps. The page don't exist when I click cancel, but the code is executed and I don't know why.

Comment: Read the answer in this thread [application-current-mainpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912056/application-current-mainpage-vs-navigation-pushasync-vs-navigation-pushmodalas) will help you to better understanding why the code is executed.

Comment: Thanks Jack, in the override OnDisappearing I could to add a validation to avoid the extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bool which checks whether or not they have cancelled before it goes to Page03. Something like this...

```
private bool isCancelled = false;

private async void GetData()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    if (!isCancelled)
        MainPage.actualPage.PushAsync(new Page03());
}

private void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isCancelled = true;
    App.Current.MainPage = new Page01();
}
```